# JavaScript if-else shorthand error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This worked

```
if(a != "") {
    $('.a').css('background','red');
}
```

but this shorthand did not

```
a != "" ? $('.a').css('background', 'red');
```

I got:

> error of unexpected end of token `;`

Comment: The ternary expression is shorthand for `if...then...else`. Your shorthand omits the `else`

Comment: @HoboSapiens I no need the else.

Comment: then you don't need a shorthand.

Comment: @HoboSapiens But how to writer shorter and cleaner code?

Comment: The `if..` *is* the clean and clear way to write this in JavaScript.. short does not mean "better" or "cleaner". I always use (and recommend) braces *and* newlines, but that's a different style consideration. The `?:` is more appropriate when - and *only when* - the results are going to be used as an expression. Otherwise, use `if..[else..]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here in this case, you don't want to have `else` case and `shorthand` must not come without `?, :` operators!

So, This is also an option:

```
a != "" && $('.a').css('background', 'red');
```

`$('.a').css('background', 'red');` will only be called if `a != ""`. This is called [Short-circuiting](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php).

It is not commonly used in cases like this and you really shouldn't write code like this. I will suggest this approach instead:

```
if(a != "")  $('.a').css('background','red');
```

OR better :

```
if(a != "") { $('.a').css('background','red'); }
```

You should write readable code at all times;

If you are worried about file size, just create a minified version of it with help of one of the thousands of JS compressors. (just take a look at [Google's Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home))

Comment: Even the inline `if` isn't very pretty. It could be difficult (at first glance) to determine where the conditioni ends and the block begins, especially if the condition is complicated. Adding `{ ... }` would help, but that defeats the purpose. (BTW, +1 for the suggestion of using JS Compressors.)

Comment: Yes @jsve, it should always avoid confusion, as OP requires. So, edited the answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Shorthands

#### IF THEN

This uses **&&**

```
a != "" && $('.a').css('background', 'red');
```

When one side evaluates to true, the other is run.

---

#### IF THEN ELSE

The syntax for this is **IF?THEN:ELSE**

```
a != "" ? $('.a').css('background', 'red') : $('.a').css('background', 'blue');
```

You cannot simply 'leave' out part of this

## Issue

The short hand you're using is an **IF THEN ELSE**. You are treating it as an **IF ELSE**. To fix this, use the following code instead:

```
a != "" && $('.a').css('background', 'red');
```

When you leave out the other side is an **IF ELSE THEN** statement, it is similar to writing

```
if (a != "") {
    $('.a').css('background', 'red')
} else
```

---

The compiler is expecting a `:` to denote the next part of your shorthand but it sees a `;`

## More

I would discourage you from writing minified code because it is confusing and difficult to read and modify. I recommend using an [online compressor such as **jscompress.com**](http://jscompress.com). To write clean and neat code, write it out

```
if (a !== "") {
    $('.a').css('background', 'red');
}
```

That makes it clear to see what you're doing, less error prone, and easier to edit.

---

If you want to learn good coding practices, check out [**JSLint**](http://www.jslint.com) *(Not JSHint)*

---

[I learned my shorthands from **here**](http://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/)

Comment: @Vikrat the grammar was correct before. An is used before a vowel.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is of the form:

```
(condition) ? (foo) : (bar);
```

which is shorthand for

```
if (condition) {
    // do whatever foo is
} else {
    // do whatever bar is
}
```

You ***must*** supply something for the `else` condition if you are using this syntax (in the case above, `bar`).

---

What I think you want to do is this:

```
a != "" && $('.a').css('background', 'red');
```

which will only run `$('.a').css('background', 'red');` if `a != ""`. This is called (as [Vikrant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3682162/vikrant) pointed out) [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

---

**References:**

- Ternary Expression: [MDN documentation: Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- Short-Circuit Evaluation: [MDN documentation: Logical Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

Comment: Whilst this is a technically valid solution it's difficult to see how this is an improvement over `if () {}`. It certainly adds nothing to the clarity.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, I totally agree, however, the OP asked for a shorthand way of expressing the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this... Hope I remember correctly and do better than minifier.

```
a !== "" && $('.a').css('background','red');
```